# Why "java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value..." is happened with MySQL and JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I develop API with following tools.

- Kotlin 1.3.61
- Spring Boot 2.2.4
- Docker
- JPA
- MySQL 8.0

Application and database are build with docker.

I tried insert data with UUID, but "java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value..." was happened.

The stacktrace is following.

```
Hibernate: select todo0_.id as id1_0_0_, todo0_.content as content2_0_0_, todo0_.created_at as created_3_0_0_, todo0_.is_done as is_done4_0_0_, todo0_.updated_at as updated_5_0_0_ from todo todo0_ where todo0_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into todo (content, created_at, is_done, updated_at, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-03-21 08:54:02.257  WARN 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
2020-03-21 08:54:02.273 ERROR 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect string value: '\xFA>\xE8cD\xF6...' for column 'id' at row 1
2020-03-21 08:54:02.477 ERROR 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xFA>\xE8cD\xF6...' for column 'id' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3226) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3751) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1344) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:435) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3221) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2389) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:712) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.todo.application.service.TodoRecordService.store(TodoRecordService.kt:13) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.example.todo.presentation.TodoStoreController.invoke(TodoStoreController.kt:15) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I researched this error, and I could find the article which said this cause was character set.

But My my.conf already set character set to utf8mb4 and database variables were utf8mb4.

my.conf

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
explicit-defaults-for-timestamp=1
general-log=1
general-log-file=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

result of "show variables like "chara%";"

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8                           |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

My application.yml was not written character set expressly, so I added "?character_set_server=utf8mb4" following.

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: localhost
---
spring:
  profiles: localhost
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todo_db?character_set_server=utf8mb4
    username: user
    password: password
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  data:
    web:
      base-path: /customer
---
spring:
  profiles: docker
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://dbserver/todo_db?character_set_server=utf8mb4
    username: user
    password: password
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  data:
    web:
      base-path: /customer
```

After added character set to application.yml, I tried to insert again but result was not changed.

Why "java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value..." is happend?

---

the part of source codes are following.

ddl

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `todo_db`.`todo` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `content` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `is_done` BOOLEAN,
    `created_at` DATETIME,
    `updated_at` DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

entity class

```
package com.example.todo.infrastructure.entity

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
class Todo(

        @Id
        val id: UUID?,

        var content: String,

        @Column(name = "is_done")
        var isDone: Boolean,

        @Column(name = "created_at")
        @CreationTimestamp
        val createdAt: LocalDateTime?,

        @Column(name = "updated_at")
        @UpdateTimestamp
        val updatedAt: LocalDateTime?
)
```

repository class

```
package com.example.todo.infrastructure.repository

import com.example.todo.infrastructure.entity.Todo
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import java.util.*

@Repository
interface TodoRepository : JpaRepository<Todo, UUID> {
}
```

service class

```
package com.example.todo.application.service

import com.example.todo.infrastructure.entity.Todo
import com.example.todo.infrastructure.repository.TodoRepository
import com.example.todo.presentation.request.TodoRequest
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import java.util.*

@Service
class TodoRecordService (private val todoRepository: TodoRepository) {
    fun store(request: TodoRequest): Todo {
        val todoEntity = Todo(UUID.randomUUID(), request.content, request.isDone, null, null)
        return todoRepository.save(todoEntity)
    }
}
```

Comment: You've included everything _except_ the Java code, and I think we need to see that too.

Comment: Check the string. It may contain a zero value. In any case what the error message indicates the string may be containing garbage.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your comment. Some codes are added to question zone.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you for your comment. I will check the string.

Comment: Always look very, very carefully at the original exception even though it may be way down in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i solved added this to yml config:

spring:
jpa:
hibernate:
use-new-id-generator-mappings: false